# C# Chart class not rendering in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, charts

I'm trying to test charting functionality in my C#.NET 4.0 MVC application following [this](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart) guide.

Here is my View code:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
   .AddTitle("Employees")
   .AddSeries(chartType: "column",
      xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
      yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
   .Write();


}
```

When I run the application it just gives me a bunch of ASCII characters:

> JFIF``C    $.'
>   ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342C 
>   2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222X"
>   }!1AQa"q2#BR$3br
>   %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz
>   w!1AQaq"2B#3R$4&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz?
>   ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( (
>   +LL1V*Fwc@uQUn:j((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
>   P';ա2nd4x Iv {Ϳ*Kmv#Y@P;kݖ
>   ^N7f+* =huE@co
>   qG(ܒI)V0AA}{6ND!\CW 3Q
>   3Q}vNZ4
>   bcy?xZfFtfoNjG/CxZf9k2΂hhEş"
>   c-Fg:CjҨV
>   NH1yEsl?}"AEsl?}"AEsl?}"

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot/proceed?  I'm just looking for a simple bar graph solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Nothing wrong with your posted code.

Comment: Yeah, the code is good which is why I'm puzzled as to why it's spewing out the ASCII garbage instead of rendering the simple graph?  At a loss

Comment: Note that the tutorial you're following, which works perfectly well, is for a _Web Site_ project template, not MVC. Each project template adds their own specific assemblies, folder/file structure, etc, so don't expect things to be fully interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have the same problem, and I solve using another logic, and works fine:

I remove de partial view (cshtml) and change the signature on Controller to return a **Chart** type:

```
        public Chart GetGrafico(int dias, int idDepartamento, int idPgto)
    {
        try
        {
            int idEmpresa = login.GetUsuario(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).IdEmpresa;
            DateTime inicial = DateTime.Today.Date;
            DateTime final = inicial.AddDays(dias);
            var grafico = service.GetGrafico(inicial, final, idEmpresa, idDepartamento, idPgto);

            Chart myChart = new Chart(800, 600)
                .AddTitle("Vencimentos futuros")
                .AddSeries(
                name: "Vencimentos",
                xValue: grafico.Select(x => x.Dia).ToArray(),
                yValues: grafico.Select(x => x.Valor).ToArray()).Write();                 

            return myChart;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Then in the Index.cshtml I just add a image tag:

```
<img id="img" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#gerarGrafico').click(function () {
    $('#img').attr('src', '/Erp/Grafico/GetGrafico?dias=30&idDepartamento=0&idPgto=0');
});
```

So now when a click in the button, the jQuery function just set the attr src of image, it works fine.